# Meta reputation out of sync in "Your Communities" sub-menu and mobile app

Tags: bug, reputation, user-accounts, stack-exchange

I know reputation is periodically synced between the parent site and meta site, so reputation will occasionally be different.

However, the reputation is greatly out of sync in the "Your Communities" sub-menu and mobile app (iOS 12.1.3, StackApp 1.6.6.2)

[image: Rep differences between header and submenu]

[image: Rep differences on mobile app]

Comment: I am reproducing this, with a difference of around 500 rep between the communities display and my real rep

Comment: Same here, can reproduce on the full site with ~200 rep discrepancy.

Comment: This was also reported on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317269/meta-sites-in-your-communities-display-different-reputation). Not sure what's causing it but I'll see if we can look into it.